# VPN Connection pooling?

Tags: vpn, linux-networking, pfsense

I'm having a problem on PFSense https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=23914.0
where I can only connect one client with a PPTP VPN to a VPN Server outside out network. PFsense is our firewall and it only allows one PPTP connection from a single IP.

Is it possible to setup some way that all the clients on our network connect to the VPN server as if from one IP? It is possibly to pool the VPN connections?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a way to accommodate that. Not a practical one at least.

PPTP is no longer a VPN, it's effectively an insecure tunnel. The answer is really that you shouldn't be using PPTP. No modern, secure VPN option will have a problem with 1 client or a million.

There isn't any built-in functionality for a PPTP client in pfSense. It's not all that difficult to hack in if you really understand all the underlying pieces. Really sounds like you need a site to site VPN via something that's actually intended for site to site VPNs and is secure (IPsec, OpenVPN). I wouldn't bother trying to get PPTP to work in this scenario.